# speed up play of audio file , SoundCloud in iPhone

Tags: ios, performance, soundcloud

How can I speed up the download of audio file from sound cloud to my app in iphone. there is a long waiting time between the click play button and start of playing. (I just play the files no downloading )

what is the best solution to use ? can the download be asynchronies to make it faster ? 
I'm using JSON to get the data and AVAudioPlayer to play sound.
any suggestions will be helpful

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Audio Streamer class integrated to my project and it works very good

Answer (score 0):

I have found a really good answer here to speed up the playing using AVPlayer.

[Soundcloud iOS API - playing sound from link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177594/soundcloud-ios-api-playing-sound-from-link)

I've tried already and the response is really good!

The code is:

```
NSString *trackID = @"100026228";
NSString *clientID = @"YOUR_CLIENT_ID";
NSURL *trackURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/%@/stream?client_id=%@", trackID, clientID]];

NSURLSessionTask *task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:trackURL completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    // self.player is strong property
    self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:nil];
    [self.player play];
}];

[task resume];
```